# Unzip files and folder in Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, zip, cordova-plugins, unzip

I'm currently developing a Cordova app. I'm trying to unzip a zip file. I used the `cordova-plugin-zip` to make this possible. However my zip file is mixed with folder and files. When I tried to unzip it, it only extract the files and the folders are ignore. How to make this possible? Thanks!

Here's some of my codes.

```
 public static UnZipFile(filename: string, extractedpath: string) {

  var promise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
     AppBridge.createDirectory(extractedpath); //This creates the directory path
     var filePath: string = AppBridge.getZipName(filename); //Get the zip file name
     var destination: string = AppBridge.outputDirectory(extractedpath); //Get the output directory

     zip.unzip(filePath, destination);

   });
}
```

The `AppBridge` is written in C#, my project somehow mixed in .Net Core and Cordova. That's why the C# kind of limited of what can do. I just used it to get some information to Windows.

Comment: Could you add some code of what you have?

Comment: @Yesub I already update it with code. Hope it is clear.

Comment: What Object is the zip from zip.unzip ?

Comment: I think this is the source code of it. Click [here](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip/blob/master/zip.js)

Comment: You think or you're sure about it ?

Comment: @Yesub I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not the first on to have the same issue : [Recursive unzip? #12](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip/issues/12) 
The problem could be because you're unzipping on a read-only filesystem.

Can you change something about that ?

Another solution is to use another [plugin](https://github.com/michogar/extract-zipfile) which seems to be working. But I haven't try my self.